Is it possible to have working links to local files in an MHTML file?
I cannot find any information on how to insert links into MHTML files.
I have a local MHTML file (the file was generated by Chrome). It contains the following code:
<a href=3D"file:///C:/dir1/file=
1.mhtml" target=3D"_self">link to C:/dir1/file1.mhtml</a>

When I click this link, I want the browser (Chrome) to visit the file whose URL is file:///C:/dir1/file1.mhtml. But if I click the link, nothing happens. The browser does not react. Why? If I place the cursor over the link text, copy link address, then paste it into the URL bar and press Enter, the browser loads the page as expected.
